# Autocomplete text view and custom adapter getting the selected item

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I have doubt regarding [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) and the Custom Adapter backing it. Since I am using a custom adapter, a class extending `ArrayAdapter<Locality>` (where Locality is a plain model class), is it possible to get the Selected Item when the user types some text but doesn't click the item from dropdown.

For example, suppose I am using [setOnItemClickListener (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)). I can get which Item was clicked and hence selected. This looks simple, but what happens if the user types the complete text without clicking any of the item from the suggestions dropdown. The **[onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long))** will never fire, and there won't be any selected item even though the text that the user typed is a valid item text (Locality Name in my case).

One option would be to check the text that is typed in, and find the matching locality form the server call using that text. But that surely looks crude, so I am hoping for some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can set addTextChangeListener on your autocompletetextview like this

```
 myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            readSearchTerm(s.getText().toString());
        }
    });



 private List<String> readSearchTerm(String userInput) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> searchItemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < myObjectList.size(); i++) {

            myObjectList.get(i).objectName = myObjectList.get(i).objectName
                    .replace(" ", "-");

            String itemArray[] = myObjectList.get(i).objectName.split("-");

            for (int j = 0; j < itemArray.length; j++) {

                Log.i("mini", "Item:" + itemArray[j]);
                if (itemArray[j].contains(userInput)) {
                    searchItemList.add(myObjectList.get(i).objectName);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return searchItemList;

}
```

just change read search term method according to your code.You will get the filtered list or items matching that item

Comment: I already have that list. As the user types a character, I fetch the matching items from server and present it as dropdown. So at any point I already have a list of items matching the currently typed text. Its just that if the user doesn't select any item from the list by clicking, the selected item is not available in my code. Although I could construct it from the text typed, I was looking for a cleaner approach